# algorithm for reserving access to limited licenses

Tags: algorithm

We have a situation where there are less licenses(for GUI testing tool silktest) and more users.

I am trying to build a system where the access to the licenses will be through reservations.

To execute an automation suite , user has to create a reservation which will in turn use up one license.Meanwhile the other licenses will be free.

A simple FIFO queue will not solve it , as a single user can execute only one suite at a time.

Is there any standard algorithm that will help to effectively distribute the licenses.

Comment: Do I understand it right that a single user may create more reservations at the same time, but he should get more than one only if that wouldn't limit other users? Do you know how long will each reservation last? Are the reservations created ahead of time (“I will need a license on Monday at 11”) or not (“I need the license right now”)?

Comment: Also, would a simple [round-robin scheduling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Round-robin_scheduling) be enough?

Comment: 1) Yes, single user may create multiple reservations ( but will only be used after the user's current execution is complete).A user does not need more than once license at a time , as only one instance of silktest can be run in one machine.
2)Time may varies completion of each execution.
3)No, not ahead of time.
4) A round-robin on all reservations can assign multiple licenses to single user ,which  would go waste.

Comment: And the reservations are first-come first-served? Also can you please clarify "Time may varies completion of each execution" comment?  Like svik asked, is the reservations ahead of time or "now"?  Are you saying that I reserve the license for a certain start time, but without an end time, or do I reserve it for a specified amount of time, at the end of which the license is yanked?

Answer (score 0):

Define an epoch. stats happen over an epoch. (Say two hours).

Define a tick. license requests are accepted/resolved every tick. (Say 30 seconds)

Keep stats on how long each license is held for, and by whom.

Assign a weight to each user, ewhich will be decreased the more they use the license but only for a set time.

Every tick:

1. Gather who wants a license.
2. Record releases of licenses and collect license checkout time per user stats.
3. For each available license:
4. Chose between requesting users with the highest weight then longest wait time. Randomly if more than one user ties on the two criteria.
5. Arrange to decrement the weight of the winning users for time equal to the prior average time they held the license for, plus the time they keep this license for.

Every epoch:

1. Adjust the stats so they don't overrun

Hopefully this will adjust license checkouts automatically for differences in users use of licenses. Those wanting to use it for long times or frequently or occasionally should still get access to a license that over time will hopefully even out.

ather